# XSLT condition in for each loop do not extract all the value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file which looks like, "ROL" nodes can be 0 to n

```
<Message>
<ROL>
    <ROL.1>
        <ROL.1.1>1</ROL.1.1>
    </ROL.1>
    <ROL.2>
        <ROL.2.1>AD</ROL.2.1>
    </ROL.2>
    <ROL.3>
        <ROL.3.1>FH</ROL.3.1>
    </ROL.3>
    <ROL.4>
        <ROL.4.1>A</ROL.4.1>
        <ROL.4.2>B</ROL.4.2>
        <ROL.4.3>C</ROL.4.3>
        <ROL.4.4>D</ROL.4.4>
</ROL>
<ROL>
    <ROL.1>
        <ROL.1.1>1</ROL.1.1>
    </ROL.1>
    <ROL.2>
        <ROL.2.1>AD</ROL.2.1>
    </ROL.2>
    <ROL.3>
        <ROL.3.1>PP</ROL.3.1>
    </ROL.3>
    <ROL.4>
        <ROL.4.1>W</ROL.4.1>
        <ROL.4.2>X</ROL.4.2>
        <ROL.4.3>Y</ROL.4.3>
        <ROL.4.4>Z</ROL.4.4>
</ROL>
</Message>
```

My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Message/ROL">
  <xsl:for-each select="ROL.3/ROL.3.1">
        <aa> <xsl:value-of select="."/> </aa>
        <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test=".='FH'">
                <Family>
                  <xsl:attribute name="FHFrist"> <xsl:value-of     select="//ROL.4/ROL.4.3"/>  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="FHLast"> <xsl:value-of select="//ROL.4/ROL.4.2"/> </xsl:attribute>
                </Family>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='PP'">
                <Primary>
                  <xsl:attribute name="FHFrist"> <xsl:value-of select="//ROL.4/ROL.4.3"/>  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="FHLast"> <xsl:value-of select="//ROL.4/ROL.4.2"/> </xsl:attribute>
                </Primary>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>   
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Result I am getting:

```
<aa>FH</aa>
<Family FHFrist="C" FHLast="B"/>
<aa>PP</aa>
<Primary FHFrist="C" FHLast="B"/>
```

Desired Result:

```
<aa>FH</aa>
<Family FHFrist="C" FHLast="B"/>
<aa>PP</aa>
<Primary FHFrist="Y" FHLast="X"/>
```

My problem is that XSLT is not able to extract the value ROL.4.3 and ROL.4.2 based on this condition-
            when test=".='FH'
            when test=".='PP'
It seems like it is extracting the value of first instance, why? how can i Fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XPath `//` starts searching from the beginning of the file.

e.g. this will get you from ROL.3.1 to ROL.4.3

```
./../../ROL.4/ROL.4.3
```

Your desired result would include navigating from one ROL element to another.

My assumption is that you would remain within the context of a single ROL, therefore I would of thought that the following result was desired?

```
<aa>FHCP</aa>
<Family FHFrist="C" FHLast="B"/>
<aa>PP</aa>
<Primary FHFrist="Y" FHLast="X"/>
```

Based on the above result...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Message/ROL">
  <xsl:for-each select="ROL.3/ROL.3.1">
    <aa>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </aa>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='FH'">
        <Family>
          <xsl:attribute name="FHFrist">
            <xsl:value-of select="./../../ROL.4/ROL.4.3" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="FHLast">
            <xsl:value-of select="./../../ROL.4/ROL.4.2" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </Family>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=".='PP'">
        <Primary>
          <xsl:attribute name="FHFrist">
            <xsl:value-of select="./../../ROL.4/ROL.4.3" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="FHLast">
            <xsl:value-of select="./../../ROL.4/ROL.4.2" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </Primary>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>   
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your response. Yes you are correct about the desired result. I just corrected my post. But when I used XSLT suggested by you, I do not get any results at all?

Comment: It worked, i did a silly typo. Thanks for your help. One more questions, can you please explain, "./../../"?

Comment: ./ = navigation from current node, ../ = navigation from parent node. Therefore, ./../../ == current node's parent's parent.